# FullSimplify and Min/Max

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I was coding up some bounds propagation in some constraint satisfaction code I was playing with and decided to see if Mathematica could simplify an expression involving Min and Max. I extracted the essence of what it seemed not to be able to do.

For example:

```
FullSimplify[Max[a, Max[b, c]]]
```

gives what I expect:

```
Max[a, b, c]
```

But

```
FullSimplify[Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z]]
```

doesn't:

```
Max[a, -z + Max[b + z, c + z]]
```

Often though Mathematica knows more than me. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Curious:  `Max[a, FullSimplify[Max[b + z, c + z] - z]]` works.

Comment: `FullSimplify[Max[b + z, c + z] - z]` yields a `Piecewise` expression, not `Max[b,c]` as you might expect. Suppose that has something to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)

```
Simplify[Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z]] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

```
Max[a, Simplify[Max[b + z, c + z] - z]] // PiecewiseExpand
```

[image]

```
% == %%

(* True *)
```

Comment: Well that doesn't really enlighten me any. I tried FindInstance[
 Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z] != Max[a, b, c], {a, b, c, z}] and it found no instances. So I am not missing something.

Comment: interesting, `((a - b >= 0 && b - c >= 0) || (b - c < 0 && a - c >= 0))` should reduce to  `a>=b&&a>=c` which would make the equivalence to `Max[a,b,c]` more clear.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the problem is that there is no built-in transformation like the one the OP seems be to thinking of.  We can try adding it, and the desired result occurs:

```
Simplify[Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, 
   Replace[#, HoldPattern[Max[args__] + b_] :> Max @@ ({args} + b)] &}]

(*  Max[a, b, c]  *)
```

If we consider the domain of `Max`, which includes `±Infinity` in addition to the real numbers, then the above result is only generically correct, which may explain why the desired result takes some work to obtain:

```
Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z] /. {a -> 1, b -> -Infinity, c -> 10, z -> Infinity}
(*  Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression warning  *)
(*  Out[]= Indeterminate  *)

Max[a, b, c] /. {a -> 1, b -> -Infinity, c -> 10, z -> Infinity}
(*  Out[]= 10  *)
```

Nonetheless, even if you exclude infinities, the needed transformation does not seem to exist:

```
FullSimplify[Max[a, Max[b + z, c + z] - z], Thread[-∞ < {a, b, c, z} < ∞]]
(*  Max[a, -z + Max[b + z, c + z]]  *)
```

Comment: That's very interesting. Thank you for this.